# Como recortar parte de um bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Quero criar um `Bitmap` que seu conteúdo seja uma parte de outro `Bitmap`

---

**Por exemplo:**

Possuo um Bitmap de (400x900)
width = 400
height = 900

Quero recortar ele nas dimensões (400x400) com o objetivo de deixar a altura igual a largura ignorando o restante da imagem.

---

O resultado deve ficar desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Montei este algoritmo, porém ele demora muito tempo executando:

```
private Bitmap reparteImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    //PASSA WIDTH PARA WIDTH E HEIGHT
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, w, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
    for(int x=0;x<bmp.getWidth();x++){
        for(int y=0;y<bmp.getHeight();y++){
            bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitmap.getPixel(x, y));
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

---

Existe uma forma mais rápida para realizar este procedimento utilizando Canvas ou alguma outra classe que trabalhe com Imagens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o método estático [createBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) da classe Bitmap:

```
Bitmap createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

No seu caso use-o assim:

```
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, 0, 0, 400, 400);
```